# ccboot iSCSI not supported on client

Tags: pxe, thin-client, iscsi

I'm trying to implement some thin clients and I've tried openthinclient, but I don't know how to make the client boot to Win XP. I can only boot to OpenThinClientOS.

So I tried another thin client server called CCboot.

It worked on my VirtualBox, but when I try to implement it on real PC, 
it says:

```
could not initialize iSCSI device : not supported (0x blah blah)
could not boot from iscsi : my.ip.address.TCserver::: Not Supported
```

What must I do?

Do you guys have another solution? (like not using ccboot anymore because I can't find any review for best thin client server application)